# The Linkedin APP access token give me an error

Tags: linkedin-api

In https://developer.linkedin.com/ i create an APP and then i create an access token but after I tried the token it sends back the following error

access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=urn:li:person:gek-terna' from origin 'https://gekterna.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to prefight request doesn't access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resourse.

Can anyone help me?

I made some "digging" and I found that i have to have access to the servers hosting the LinkedIn API, reaching out to LinkedIn support may not directly resolve the CORS issue